# Why does setting Maven surefire forkMode to never speed up my unit tests?

Tags: maven, junit, surefire

With the maven surefire plugin I can set forkMode to never - doing this speeds up execution on 1000 unit tests from 7 minutes to 1:40.

Why is this making such a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned on debug for maven and it became clear the pom was referencing a parent pom version which was setting `forkMode=always` for the surefire plugin, overriding the default value.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `forkMode` is `once`.  This means surefire creates a separate JVM to run the tests.  Seems on your build system, creating and cleaning up the extra JVM is taking a while.